# Parallel tangents to graph of $f(x)=2e^{3x}$ and $g(x)=5x^3$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x)=2e^{3x}$ and $g(x)=5x^3$. At what $x$-value do the graphs of $f$ and $g$ have parallel tangents?

I get that I have to set their derivatives equal to each other, but how do I solve for $x$?

$$6e^{3x}=15x^2$$

Comment: Try taking the natural log of both sides

Comment: @Pendronator That only gives $\log(6) + 3x= \log(15) + 2\log x$, which is no easier to solve for $x$ than the original. This system of equation is not solvable using elementary functions, but can be using the product log.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want (or cannot) use Lambert function, this is a strictly numerical problem.

You need to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=6 e^{3 x}-15 x^2$$ Using Newton method with $x_0=0$, you will obtain the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -0.3333333333 \\
 2 & -0.3658574286 \\
 3 & -0.3655221445 \\
 4 & -0.3655221049
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

This system of equations has no 'elementary' solution. So this is meant to be done numerically. You can do this in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%206%20e%5E%283x%29%3D15%20x%5E2) for example. We find
$$
x \approx -0.365522
$$

Answer (score 0):

This would be solvable using the Lambert-W Function.

If $f(x)=xe^x$, then its inverse is $W(x)$.

This means if you see an equation $y=xe^x$, then $x=W(y)$ using the properties of inverse functions.

A side note would be that the domain of $W(x)$ is $x\geq-\frac{1}{e}$

For your question: $6e^{3x}=15x^2$

$\frac{6}{15}=x^2e^{-3x}$

$\frac{\sqrt6}{\sqrt15}=|x|e^{-\frac{3}{2}x}$, for the absolute value of x, we will only take the negative x-values so that it satisfies the Lambert-W function's domain.

$\frac{3\sqrt6}{2\sqrt{15}}=-\frac{3}{2}xe^{-\frac{3}{2}x}$

$-\frac{3}{2}x=W(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}})$

$x=-\frac{2}{3}W(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}})$

$x\approx-0.36552$